# SQL: how to count entries in multiple tables by value?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `question` & `field`. I need to count entries , with coincidental value of `template_id` (both tables contains).

Please advice, how to do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the requirement(may be with an example)? What do you mean by coincidental value here? Also, mention which database are you using?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: It would help a bit if you showed us what you have already done or at least describe the tables and where there is foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(q.*)
from question q
left join field f on f.template.id = q.template_id
```

In StackOverflow one should show ones own attempt, show that some effort was done.

Above `inner join` is probably what you meant. Try first `select q.*, f.*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TotalRecords

FROM question q
    INNER JOIN field f ON f.template_id = q.template_id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks, I will remember this for future posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of *distinct* `template_id` in the two tables, use `JOIN` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
select count(distinct q.template_id)
from question q join
     field f
     on f.template_id = q.template_id;
```

If you use `count(*)` you will get a count of matching *rows*, not `template_id`s, so duplicates will affect the result.

If `template_id` is known to be unique in one of the tables (say `question`), then `exists` is probably more efficient:

```
select count(*)
from question q
where exists (select 1
              from field f
              where f.template_id = q.template_id
             );
```